# Отображение символов табуляции и пробелов

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql

Как включить отображение пробелов и табуляций в редакторе запросов в Sql Server Management Studio 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так. Откройте реестр и исправьте в нем значение ключа на 1

> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\...\Tools\Shell\Text Editor\Visible Whitespace`

где ... - это версия вашего продукта.